# How to expand a rational function as a single fraction

Tags: simplifying-expressions

This has been annoying me for a long time. I want a rational function to be represented in the form

$$\frac{a_nx^n+....a_0x^0}{b_mx^m+....b_0x^0}$$

But this seems to be quite difficult. Mathematica really loves to factor things out. //ExpandAll usually gives me a sum of bunch of rational functions. I just want the numerator to be a straightforward polynomial and the denominator to be a straightforward polynomial.

I can //Together to get a single fraction and //Expand the numerator and denominator separately, and then combine them by hand, but that is very annoying and it feels like there should be a command to do this. The form I wrote above is *the* most common rational function form, so why would it be so difficult to arrive at?

For example what do I need to do the fraction below to get it to be a polynomial divided by a polynomial?

```
-2/n^3 + (32 n)/(1 - 8 n^2 + 16 n^4)
```

Comment: Actually the `Together` plus `Expand` on numerator and denominator is likely to be your best bet. `Together` typically does not actually factor but it also does not go out of its way to avoid factors, and sometimes it feels a need to do a square-free factorization. It can be a bit headstrong that way.

Comment: I think `ExpandNumerator` and `ExpandDenominator` in certain cases can help. Try `-2/n^3 + (32 n)/(1 - 8 n^2 + 16 n^4) // Together //ExpandDenominator // ExpandNumerator` for your example.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the commands `ExpandNumerator` and `ExpandDenominator` .

```
-2/n^3 + (32 n)/(1 - 8 n^2 + 16 n^4) // Together // 
    ExpandNumerator // ExpandDenominator

(*   (-2 + 16 n^2)/(n^3 - 8 n^5 + 16 n^7)  *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Together[-2/n^3 + (32 n)/(1 - 8 n^2 + 16 n^4)]
(*(2 (-1 + 8 n^2))/(n^3 (-1 + 4 n^2)^2)*)
```

Comment: It factors the numerator and the denominator. The result is not a straightforward polynomial. It is a factored polynomial in the numerator and the denominator.

Comment: This works: F[x_] := TraditionalForm[Expand[Numerator[Together[x]]]]/
 TraditionalForm[Expand[Denominator[Together[x]]]] , but is there really no default function to see a rational function in the form I want?

Comment: The function [`NumeratorDenominator`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumeratorDenominator.html) was introduced in v12.0.  `F[x_] := TraditionalForm[Divide @@ Expand@NumeratorDenominator@Together@x]`

Answer (score 0):

Apply `Factor` or `Together` to the expression, separate the numerator and denominator, then `Expand` and form the fraction.

```
eq = -2/n^3 + (32 n)/(1 - 8 n^2 + 16 n^4);

(#1 / #2) &@@ Expand[Through[{Numerator, Denominator}[Together[eq]]]] // TraditionalForm
```

$$\frac{16 n^2-2}{16 n^7-8 n^5+n^3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
With[{eq = -2/n^3 + (32 n)/(1 - 8 n^2 + 16 n^4)},  Inactive@Evaluate@
    Divide @@ ((Expand@#@Simplify@eq) & /@ {Numerator, Denominator})]
    // TeXForm
```

which returns
$$ \left(16 n^2-2\right)/\left(16 n^7-8 n^5+n^3\right) $$